# bad default revision HEAD

Tags: git, logging, branch

When I do:
    git log
, I get message:

`fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`

, if I do `git fsck`, I get:

```
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references
dangling blob 965fb7997c335172263ad1e220959ae2c733ed19
```

and `git branch` gives me empty output.

What is wrong with my repo, and how to fix it?

I tried `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master`, but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out what was the problem, I never actually did the first commit. ;)

Forgot about that repo, because I made changes there long time ago.